# Findout addition/Deletion/Changes through linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
DataTable dtprev = new DataTable();
dtprev.Columns.Add("pref");
dtprev.Columns.Add("field1");
dtprev.Columns.Add("field2");
dtprev.Columns.Add("field3");

DataTable dtnew = dtprev.Clone();

dtprev.Rows.Add("h20", "50", "100", "150");
dtprev.Rows.Add("h20", "25", "501", "50");
dtprev.Rows.Add("h20", "50", "50", "50");
dtprev.Rows.Add("xyz", "1", "1", "35");
dtprev.Rows.Add("abc", "1", "1", "1");
dtprev.Rows.Add("abc", "2", "3", "4");
dtprev.Rows.Add("aaa", "2", "2", "2");
dtprev.Rows.Add("bbb", "1", "1", "1");
dtprev.Rows.Add("bbb", "1", "2", "1");

dtnew.Rows.Add("h20", "50", "100", "150");
dtnew.Rows.Add("h20", "25", "501", "50");
dtnew.Rows.Add("h20", "50", "503", "50");
dtnew.Rows.Add("xyz", "1", "1", "36");
dtnew.Rows.Add("xyz", "2", "3", "44");
dtnew.Rows.Add("abc", "1", "1", "1");
dtnew.Rows.Add("bbb", "2", "3", "4");
dtnew.Rows.Add("ccc", "2", "2", "2");
```

**Expected Output**

```
"h20", "50", "100", "150" -- Matched
"h20", "25", "501", "50"  -- Matched
"h20", "50", "503", "50"  -- Changed
"xyz", "1", "1", "36"     -- Changed
"xyz", "2", "3", "44"     -- Addition
"abc", "1", "1", "1"      -- Matched
"bbb", "2", "3", "4"      -- Changed
"ccc", "2", "2", "2"      -- Addition
"abc", "2", "3", "4"      -- Deletion
"aaa", "2", "2", "2"      -- Deletion
"bbb", "1", "2", "1"      -- Deletion
```

I want to find to compare rows of these two datatables and want to find out new added rows/ deleted rows which exist in prev but not in new one and also find the out which rows are changed. I try but here "xyz" is changed and added new row.

Can anyone please help me solve it through Linq.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what constitutes the key in this list. 'xyz' is said to be changed and added - how do you know which row was added and which was changed? does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Except()`. This will return the set difference between two collections. Example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386962(v=vs.110).aspx

But let me know if you need an example more specific to your case.

Comment: Want output as 
"h20", "50", "100", "150" -- Matched 
"h20", "25", "501", "50" -- Matched 
"h20", "50", "503", "50" -- Changed 
"xyz", "1", "1", "36" -- Changed 
"xyz", "2", "3", "44" -- Addition 
"abc", "1", "1", "1" -- Matched 
"bbb", "2", "3", "4" -- Changed 
"ccc", "2", "2", "2" -- Addition 
"abc", "2", "3", "4" -- Deletion 
"aaa", "2", "2", "2" -- Deletion 
"bbb", "1", "2", "1" -- Deletion

Comment: **Want output as**
<br>"h20", "50", "100", "150" -- Matched
<br>"h20", "25", "501", "50"  -- Matched
<br>"h20", "50", "503", "50"  -- Changed
<br>"xyz", "1", "1", "36"     -- Changed
<br>"xyz", "2", "3", "44"     -- Addition
<br>"abc", "1", "1", "1"      -- Matched
<br>"bbb", "2", "3", "4"      -- Changed
<br>"ccc", "2", "2", "2"      -- Addition
<br>"abc", "2", "3", "4"      -- Deletion
<br>"aaa", "2", "2", "2"      -- Deletion
<br>"bbb", "1", "2", "1"      -- Deletion

Comment: Not sure I get what's going on with xyz. Unfortunately baby woken and on lap now! Just have a go at using Except() both ways round for add and delete. For changes you could Select out the first column initially to find duplicates then go from there with Except().